# RabbitMQ - Random queues with name "amq.gen-*" getting autogenerated

Tags: android, node.js, rabbitmq

I have a set up to send messages to durable queues from server (NodeJS) and the client (android app) listens to messages on their respective queues (each android device listens to its corresponding queue which is unique).

As per the RabbitMQ document, when we try to connect to a queue with empty name (i.e "") then RabbitMQ generates a random queue with name starting with "amq.gen-". But, no where from the client or server code I see that I am trying to connect to a queue with empty name but still see lot of random queues getting generated.

Can anyone help me in understanding what other scenarios might create random queues with name "amq.gen-*"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are creating queue with blank name a random queue name `amq.gen-*` will be generated.
If you are connecting to queue with blank name then, depending of method, last declared on this channel queue name will be used. If no queue was declared or method doesn't support blank queue name error will be thrown.

See [`queue.declare` method](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare) and [`domain.queue-name` domain](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.queue-name) documentation for details.

Comment: The question asker wants to know why these auto-named queues are created when the system is using real queue names.  I would also like to know since I have the same scenario.

Comment: @JamesK as it written in the original answer, when user creates queue with empty name, RabbitMQ generate that name by itself and place `amqp.gen-` as it prefix to denote that queue name is auto-generated. Please, follow links in the answer above and search there for "generated" and for "amq." to get more context of that, hope, it will help.

Comment: PS: such queues could be exclusive or have auto-delete, queues that supposed to be short-living and about to be deleted right after they did their job. In such cases it doesn't make sense to name them and user may or have to (depends on specific use case) rely on server naming logic.

Comment: 100% correct - I found that the reply queues in the code were created with no name because they don’t require one.  Always wanted to know where these auto-named queues came from, and this answer helped me a lot because it is spot on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMq generated random name queues(amq.gen-* ) if in the application you are passing empty string as a Queue name Plz check RabbitMq configuration .